unwanted reverse exclamation mark and question mark turnning up at reference URL part
has someone ever faced the same problem as in the picture where these unwanted glyphs show up near the URL?
I don't know what code section is responsible for this so sorry for no minimal reproducible example.


that is < and > in OT1 encoding, use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} (or use \texttt{...} to typeset the URL in tt font). As the text does not appear to be English, you should not be using the default OT1 encoding anway (any non-ascii letters will stop correct hypenation)

is the style <http://example.com> with <> already in your bib file or are the angle brackets being added by the bibliography formatting? (it always helps if you provide a real example not just an image of the output)

@DavidCarlisle thanks for the tip, it solved the problem.
